# Setup IPv6 on two routers with file sharing

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, ipv6, subnet

My current network is as seen below (plenty of more wifi devices but you get the idea).

```
                                                         +--------+ 
                                                         | Laptop | 
                                                         |  WiFi  | 
                                                      -> +--------+ 
                                                    -/              
+-------+        +-------------+        +----------+                
|       |        |             |        |          |                
|  ISP  | -----> |    ZyXEL    | -----> |  DD-WRT  |                
|  DSL  |        | Modem/Router|        |  Router  |                
|       |        |             |        |          |                
+-------+        +-------------+ ---+   +----------+-\              
                                    |                 -\            
                                    |                   >+---------+
                                    v                    | Desktop |
                              +--------+                 |   ETH   |
                              | RaspPi |                 +---------+
                              |  NAS   |                            
                              +--------+
```

I am looking to get IPv6 setup such that devices on the DD-WRT router are able to access the Internet using an IPv6 address. When connected to the ZyXEL router I am able to browse using an IPv6 address however I am unable to figure out how to setup the DD-WRT router to also have IPv6 addressing. An added bonus would be to have the RaspberryPi that is acting as a NAS to be accessible via devices connected to the DD-WRT router. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order for DD-WRT to dish out IPv6 addresses you will have to assign it a IPv6 address (that's just how DD-WRT) works.  Of course this is based on the assumption your build of DD-WRT even supports IPv6

Comment: The usual question: Is there a reason your ddwrt is even acting as a router in the first place? As opposed to a transparent bridge / WiFi access point. Also: what's the model of that Zyxel

Comment: The reason I am using the DD-WRT as a router is that there are actually a couple of other NAS on that router that I don't want accessible via the ZyXEL (rasp pi is running ftp publicly and NAS locally).

Comment: The ZyXEL is a PK5001z